# How to group element of the Stream in order to pick a single element based on its poperties

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Using Java 8 streams, I want to find an **actor** who acted in max number of movies in a **single year**.

##### List of Movie(s):

```java
List<Movie> movies= [

Movie{name="The Avengers",year="2011",actorList=["Tom","Chris","Robert"]},
Movie{name="Sherlock Holmes",year="2011",actorList=["Robert","Harris","Murphy"]},
Movie{name="Spiderman",year="2002",actorList=["Tobey","William","Kirsten"]},
...

]
```

##### Movie Pojo:

```java
class Movie{
   String name; 
   String year; 
   List<String> actorList; 
}
```

##### Expected output:

[**Year**, **actor**(*acted in max no of movies in a single year*), **count**(*max movies*)]

```
["2011", "Robert", 2 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that, you can group the *movies* by **year** and by **actor's name** creating a nested map. And then process its entries.

It can be done with `Collectors.groupingBy()`. You need to pass as the first argument a function (`Movie::getYear`) that extracts a **year**, and that will be the key of the map.

As a downstream collector of the `groupingBy` you need to apply `flatMapping` to extract **actors** from a *movie object*. Note, `flatMapping` expect as an argument a function takes a stream element (*movie object*) and returns a `Stream` (*of **actor's** names*).

And then a downstream collector of the `flatMapping` you need to apply `groupingBy` again to create a nested map that will group movies by **actor**. Since only a number of movies is needed, `counting()` has to be used as a downstream collector to reduce *movie objects* mapped to each actor to a number of these objects.

With that will be created an intermediate map of type `Map<String, Map<String, Long>>` that represent the total **count** of movies by **actor** for each **year**.

The next step is to create a stream over the *entry set* and *flatten* the nested map (*count of movies by actor*) by wrapping every entry in the map with a new *composed entry* of type `Map.Entry<String, Map.Entry<String, Long>>` that will contain a **year**, **actor's name** and a **count**.

And the last step is to find the *entry* with the *maximum count*.

For that operation`max()` has to applied on the stream. It expects a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) and returns a result wrapped by an `Optional`. I assume that resume is expected to be present, therefore the code below is a fail-fast implementation that will raise a `NuSuchElementExeption` in case if the stream source is empty (*no result will be found*).

`Comparator` is defined by using the static method `comparingLong()`. It will produce a comparator based on the **count** of movies.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Movie> movies =
            List.of(new Movie("The Avengers", "2011", List.of("Tom","Chris","Robert")),
                    new Movie("Sherlock Holmes", "2011", List.of("Robert","Harris","Murphy")),
                    new Movie("Spiderman", "2002", List.of("Tobey","William","Kirsten")));

    Map.Entry<String, Map.Entry<String, Long>> result =
        movies.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Movie::getYear,
                        Collectors.flatMapping(movie -> movie.getActorList().stream(),
                             Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                                                   Collectors.counting()))))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(entryYear -> entryYear.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                    .map(entryActor -> Map.entry(entryYear.getKey(),
                                            Map.entry(entryActor.getKey(), 
                                                      entryActor.getValue()))))
            .max(Comparator.comparingLong(entry -> entry.getValue().getValue()))
            .orElseThrow(); // NoSuchElementExeption will be thrown is the result wasn't found (if stream is empty)

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**Output**

```
2011=Robert=2
```